# Angular NVD3 y-axis scale

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have an app that creates discrete bar charts. For some odd reason (which seems to be an internal error in the library), the y-axis scales to a data value which has the LOWEST number of integers in the value. For example, one data set has `(1750, 1056, 1200, 850)`. The y-axis scales the maximum range to "850", even though the other numbers are all larger. I've tried using the forceY function, setting the maximum range value to the callback of the data value in my json, but it doesn't work. The problem only corrects itself if all of the numbers in the data set have the same number of integers in the value (i.e. all hundreds, thousands, etc). What is going on and is there a way to fix it??

For reference, here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VoaVmu?p=preview). Go to the "Top 5 SIC by Comments" report chart to see what I mean. The same problem occurs with the "Top 5 Topics by Comments" report chart as well. If anyone has any insight as to how to fix this problem, please let me know. Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: You solved the problem? I have the same issue... Thanks!

Comment: Me too! I have the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752071/angular-nvd3-bar-chart-y-axis-scaling-bug-angularjs